# html table with Bootstrap, cells expanding rules

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want use a very simple page with bootstrap to display matchs results.

Something like this : http://plnkr.co/uLKUouQPdvlcaH95SOxU .

By default, each cell takes a `width` proportional with its content length; it's fine for column 2 and 4 but not for 1 and 3.

Actually I fix the issue with fixed `widths` but is there a better way?
Can I ask to some columns to take only the minimal `width` needed and the others to split the remaining space?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could use css calc? http://caniuse.com/calc

Answer (score 1):

Calc() is not recommended as it isn't supported in IE8. You are better of using min/max-widths to help you control styling in a fluid layout. These will at least be supported in IE8.